# Oracle - Event on user connection

Tags: java, database, oracle

I want to create and listen an event which triggers on user connection in Oracle. Or, perhaps, there are some system triggers here. For example, if user connects to Oracle I need to detect this event and log it. How to do this?

Comment: Why the Java tag? Do you want to detect the event when your application connects, e.g. over JDBC?

Comment: @MickMnemonic, yes, when any applications connect! I put Java tag, because it might be implemented in Java part of Oracle.

Comment: Oracle (DB) and Java are distinct (even if Java is owned by Oracle). There is no "Java part" in the Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: Yes, you can create a logon trigger.  Google "oracle login trigger".  THere are a ton of examples.

Comment: @MickMnemonic, it is not relevant to the question. Anyway, I can create Java function and call it from select.